# Include native c++ dll in UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm new in using Universal Windows Application.
I need to include native c++ .dll in UWP  project (written in c#).

What are the main steps to follow?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you know how to use the native library outside of UWP (eg, how to use P/Invoke)?

Comment: I asked this question a while ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611410/calling-native-c-from-managed-c-sharp-in-windows-store

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link from Microsoft talking about [consume a C++/CX DLL from a UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/dlls-c-cx).

However, if you are planning to publish your UWP application at Windows App Store, you have to be very careful about what Windows API functions you use inside that DLL. Windows app store has it own certificate evaluation criteria and usually does not allow large numbers of Windows API functions used in UWP application.

If your C++/CX DLL is a pure logic or algorithm library and does not rely on prohibited Windows API, then it may be fine.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem